# startup command doesn't always work

Tags: startup-applications

I added a command in `Startup Applications` as you can see on the picture below:
[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work everytime I boot up my Ubuntu 16.04.

What is causing this and, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Sometimes the "startup applications" things can take a minute or two after boot to run. You might consider creating a script that runs that command, and then shows a GUI popup to alert you it completed. Then you could pass to script as the startup program.

Comment: Like @AndroidDev says put your command into a script but I would put 'sleep 1' as a new line in front of it. This pauses for 1 second before your command is executed. Then if not 100% predictable increase to 2, 3, etc. One or two minutes is too long in my experience.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix @AndroidDev I've changed the command to `sh -c "sleep 5 && xmodmap -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'"` and it worked three times in a row. Delaying the execution of a command seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: So should I write an answer?

Comment: @AndroidDev Sure

Comment: If you started at 5 seconds I would reduce it myself but if you're happy that's all that counts.